# start counting how many lines of show command after line 20

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I am trying to write a code  for counting how many lines after line 20

```
def line_count(file_name,start=20):
    num_lines = 0
    with open(file_name,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            num_lines += 1
    print(num_lines)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the question?

Comment: I wanna count how many lines after line 20 ....I mean skipping the first 20 lines then start count

Comment: sorry ...fixed the question

Comment: So, counting all of the lines (as you do now) and then subtracting 20?

Comment: make sense ,,having problem with the syntax tho:
```                    def line_count(file_name):
                        num_lines = 0
                        with open(file_name,'r') as f:
                            for line in f:
                                num_lines += 1
                        print(num_lines - 20)```

Comment: oops    ......
sorry

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is simply counting the lines in the program and subtracting 20 from it. This is possible in a one-liner:

```
>>> len(open("file.txt").read().splitlines()) - 20
6
```

In the above example, this means that the file itself has 26 lines, which is 6 more than 20.

Comment: Or even shorter, `len(list(open("file.txt"))) - 20`. This takes advantage of the fact that Python iterate over files line by line.

Comment: @jmd_dk true, well spotted! I'm going to keep my answer as is for now, because `splitlines()` looks a little more obvious to less advanced pythonistas, but that is a good catch :)